# Где у меня ошибка?

Tags: ruby

**Задача от программы:** создать робота, который будет отвечать на вопросы.
Программа не работает: при вводе "*Как тебя зовут?*" всё равно не понимает...

**Мой код:**

```
puts "Чем могу помочь?"

answer = gets

if answer == "Как тебя зовут?"
   puts "Руби"
else
   puts "Я тебя не понял"
end
```

Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Пришло время осваивать основы отладки! После `answer = gets` поставьте `puts answer.inspect`. Ответ должен всплыть практически мгновенно :)

Answer (score 2):

```
puts "Чем могу помочь?"

answer = gets.chomp

if answer == "Как тебя зовут?"
   puts "Руби"
else
   puts "Я тебя не понял"
end
```

После ввода своего вопроса ты нажимаешь enter (т.е. делаешь перевод на новую строку \n) метод `.chomp` удаляет перевод.